# ¿Cómo obtener la ruta relativa de este objeto?

Tags: laravel-5

Envío este objeto por medio de un helper, necesito la ruta relativa para poder leerla con is_dir()... Pero no sé como obtenerla.

Objeto:

```
Directory {#305 ▼
  +"path": "C:\xampp\htdocs\public\/images/events/70484917"
  +"handle": stream resource @394 ▶}
}
```

Necesito lo siguiente: /images/events/70484917